# Variance of the gain, given a set of wagers on $n$ Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability, means, variance, gambling

Let's assume we want to wager on a given set of *n* Bernoulli trials with probabilities $p_i$ with $i \in \{1, 2, ..., n\}$ and a corresponding payoff odds $b_i$, i.e., betting a certain percentage $f_i \in (0,1)$ of our (entire) bankroll results in either, a win with a wealth increase of $f_i b_i$, or loss with a wealth decrease of $-f_i$.

Our initial capital is $X_0$. Suppose we choose the goal of maximising the expected value $E(X_n)$ after $n$ trials.

Note that $E(X)$ is the expected value for individual trials with $E(X)=(bf) p + (-f)q $.

---

Now my question is as follows, what is the variance of the gain after $n$ trials? Since we repeatedly invest a percentage $f$ of our bankroll, I figured the expected mean $E(X_n)$, would grow geometrically and thus,

$E(X_n)=E(X_{n-1})E(X_{n-2})...E(X_1)X_0$.

But I am not entirely sure what $Var(X_n)$ then would be.

The reason why I am asking is that I would like to differentiate between normal volatility around the expected mean and deviant behaviour away from it, i.e., losing more of the bankroll than one would suspect.

---

**EDIT** By stating the question I realised the answer is given by this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/52699/114901).

Comment: Notational/usage nitpick: $E(X_n)$ is a constant, so $Var(E(X_n))$ isn't what you're looking for.  You want $Var(X_n)$.  Similarly you want the "variance of the gain after $n$ trials" (no "expected"). I've edited accordingly.